# Prevent PyPI from publishing a new version until all wheels are uploaded?

Tags: python, pypi

We have a Python package which we distribute via PyPI. We create wheels for Win x64, Win x86, and Mac.

We use AppVeyor for the Windows builds and Travis for the Mac build.

The problem we have is that all the wheels don't finish at the same time, but as soon as the first wheel is uploaded to PyPI, then our package page gets rev'ed to the latest version even though all the wheels aren't uploaded.

So we're running into the situation where a user randomly tries to install our package via pip when PyPI has been rev'ed to the new version but the wheel for their platform isn't up yet, and then they get a pip error.

Is there an elegant way to solve this? I haven't found anything so far.

Thanks!
Brian

Answer (score 1):

What I just did was I downloaded all wheels manually from CI after they're all built (OK, using https://github.com/MacPython/terryfy, but that is a detail) and then uploaded them all in one go manually. Not exacty *elegant*, I know. But that does minimize the time the PyPI page is inconsistent to several minutes.